# Настройка всплывающей корзины

Tags: jquery, virtuemart, joomla

Форумчане здравствуйте! Кто сталкивался с проблемой переброски в корзину при покупке? Мне хотелось бы реализовать возможность покупки товара без обновления страницы. Почему не получается я не пойму. Помогите, пожалуйста, выйти из ситуации.

- Сайт http://kaychyk-s.ru
- Joomla!, 2.5.9.
- VirtueMart 2.0.18